# How to calculate the pre and post values ​each time an event appears on a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science, data-analysis, data-wrangling

I have a database like this example here, and I need to calculate the average, the sum and the standard deviation of the 10 minutes prior to the event and also of the 10 minutes from the event. The numbers in dataframes are just to illustrate.

```
df = data.frame(seq(ISOdatetime(2020,5,4,0,0,0), ISOdatetime(2020,5,4,0,19,0), by=(60*1)))
colnames(df) = "date"

df$results = c(18, 25, 35, 96, 100, 50, 48, 67, 36, 98, 46, 75, 67, 36, 98, 46, 75, 67, 36, 98)
df$events = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "event A", NA, NA, "event B", NA, "event C", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "event D", NA)
```

I would like to join these calculations in a new data frame, containing, the event name and date, and the values ​​of average, sum and standard deviation in the pre and also in the later moment.  Thank you for any help.

Edit:
I would like to make the previous values ​​(of sum, average and standard deviation) to the event (that is, the 10 minutes immediately preceding), and the subsequent values ​​from of the event (that is, if the event happened 10:01, I would like to take the "01" + nine minutes ahead. So, I need separate the values in "avg.pre", "sd.pre", "sum.pre" and "avg.pos", "sd.pos" and "sum.pos"

```
new.df = data.frame(c("event A", "event B", "event C", "event D")); colnames(new.df) = "events"
new.df$date.pre = c("2020-05-04 00:06:00", "2020-05-04 00:09:00", " 2020-05-04 00:11:00", " 2020-05-04 00:18:00")
new.df$avg.pre = c(53.14, 52.77...)
new.df$sd.pre = c(32.72, 31.18,...)
new.df$sum.pre = c(372, 475, 68,...)
new.df$avg.pos = c(61.71, 64.4, 25,...)
new.df$sd.pos = c(23.26, 23.06, 46,...)
new.df$sum.pos = c(617, 644, 68,...)
```

Comment: Will the 10-min interval be overlapping with other events as shown in this data?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach filter data for 10 mins before and after each event :

```
library(dplyr)

purrr::map_df(unique(na.omit(df$evets)), function(x) {
  i <- df$date[df$evets == x & !is.na(df$evets)]
  
  bind_cols(data.frame(events = x,
                       date = i), df %>%
    filter(between(date, i - 10*60, i)) %>%
    summarise(pre.avg = mean(results, na.rm = TRUE), 
              pre.sd = sd(results, na.rm = TRUE), 
              pre.sum = sum(results, na.rm = TRUE)),
    df %>%
    filter(between(date, i, i + 10*60)) %>%
    summarise(post.avg = mean(results, na.rm = TRUE), 
              post.sd = sd(results, na.rm = TRUE), 
              post.sum = sum(results, na.rm = TRUE)))
})

# events                date  pre.avg   pre.sd pre.sum post.avg  post.sd post.sum
#1 event A 2020-05-04 00:06:00 53.14286 32.72323     372 62.90909 22.42969      692
#2 event B 2020-05-04 00:09:00 57.30000 31.18066     573 67.45455 24.10960      742
#3 event C 2020-05-04 00:11:00 61.45455 27.30701     676 66.44444 23.47931      598
#4 event D 2020-05-04 00:18:00 61.81818 23.49391     680 67.00000 43.84062      134
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your script has already helped me a lot. I only ask for a new help, as I did not illustrate correctly in my example, but I would like to make the previous values ​​(of sum, average and standard deviation) to the event (that is, the 10 minutes immediately preceding), and the subsequent values ​​from of the event (that is, if the event happened 10:01, I would like to take the "01" + nine minutes ahead. I would appreciate it very much if you could help me separate these values, in "avg.pre", "sd.pre", "sum.pre" and "avg.pos", "sd.pos" and "sum.pos".

Comment: @Falves Can you check if the update is what you want?

Comment: Worked perfectly! I just changed the "filter (between (date, i, i + 10 * 60))" to "9 * 60", because I need to get the minute value of the event.
Thank you very much! It helped me and taught me a lot!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. When I ran the code in my database, I received the following error: Error: Can't recycle `..1` (size 736) to match` ..2` (size 11). Do you have any idea what this is about? I am researching because I never received this error.

Comment: I am not sure. How is this data different from your actual dataset?

Comment: Is bigger than example, with 335k rows.

Comment: Can you change the first line to `i <- df$date[df$evets == x & !is.na(df$evets)][1]` and try the answer?

Comment: Sure. This was the return: 
   `Error: Can't recycle `..2` (size 11) to match `..3` (size 10).
    Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
    Called from: signal_abort(cnd)`

Comment: I asked for the "Rerun with debug", then it shows me:
`function (cnd) 
{
  if (is_true(peek_option("rlang:::force_unhandled_error"))) {
    fallback <- cnd
  }
  else {
    signalCondition(cnd)
    fallback <- cnd("rlang_error")
  }
  last_error_env$cnd <- cnd
  fallback$message <- paste_line(conditionMessage(cnd), format_onerror_backtrace(cnd))
  stop(fallback)
}`

Comment: I don't really understand the error and why it is occurring. Can you share your complete dataset somehow?

Comment: I was thinking about how to send you this dataset and I ended up understanding where the error comes from, I hadn't noticed that there were many events with the same name throughout the dataset, so I decided to concatenate the event name to the timestamp and calculate based on this new column. That way the calculations were done properly and I got the dataframe with the results I needed. Failure of my observation. Thank you so much for all your attention and help!